# Solving a system of two time dependent ODEs leading to Burger's equation in one of the variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Suppose that I have the following system on $[a,b]$ and a given $T>0$
$$\begin{cases}
\partial_t u+\partial_x(\beta u)=0, &\forall t\in (0,T)\;\text{ with }\;u(x,0)=u_0(x),\;\; u(a,t)=u_D(t)\;\;\forall t\in [0,T],  \\
\partial_x\beta=u, &\forall t\in [0,T]\;\text{ with }\;\beta(a,t)=\beta_D(t),
\end{cases} $$
where the initial data $u_0$ and boundary data $u_D$ and $\beta_D$ are given. It seems to me that if I replace $u$ with $\beta$ in the 1st equation I get
$$\partial_{xt}\beta+\partial_x(\beta\partial_x\beta)=0\implies\partial_x(\partial_t\beta+\beta\partial_x\beta)=0\implies \partial_t\beta+\beta\partial_x\beta=f(t) $$
for some function $f$. Thus it seems $\beta$ satisfies a Burger's equation with source $f(t)$. To determine $f(t)$, I said that by taking $x=a$ one has
$$f(t)=\partial_t\beta(a,t)+\beta(a,t)\partial_x\beta(a,t)=\partial_t\beta_D(t)+\beta_D(t)\partial_xu_D(a)=\beta_D'(t)+\beta_D(t)u_D'(t). $$
Thus it seems that $\beta$ satisfies the following Burger's equation with source
$$ \begin{cases}
\partial_t\beta+\beta\partial_x\beta=\beta_D'(t)+\beta_D(t)u_D'(t),& \text{ for all }(x,t)\in(a,b)\times(0,T),\\
\beta(x,0)=\beta_D(0)+\int_a^x u(\cdot,0)=\beta_D(0)+\int_a^xu_0,& \text{ for all }x\in[a,b],\\
\beta(a,t)=\beta_D(t) & \text{ for all }t\in [0,T].
\end{cases}$$
Is the reasoning correct? If yes, how to solve for a specific example? (say we choose the data so that $f(t)=0$ and $u_0$ is simple enough)

---

*Edit:* there were many typos in the original question, they are fixed now.

Comment: (1) Notice that $\partial_x\beta(a,t)=u(a,t)=u_D(t)$, so $f(t)=\beta_D'(t)+\beta_D(t)u_D(t)$. (2) Where did the equation $\beta(x,0)=\partial_x u(x,0)=u'_0(x)$ come from?

Comment: @Gonçalo Again it's a typo, it's $\partial_x\beta(x,0)=u(x,0)$. Thanks for the remark!